# Using a linear operation of two programatically defined variables as an aesthetic in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm struggling to write a very simple wrapper to produce plots for different variables. Say my data is:

`data <- tibble(year = seq(2001,2015),var1 = rnorm(15, mean=2), var1_sd = rnorm(15, mean=1, sd=0.8), var2 = rnorm(15, mean=7), var2_sd = rnorm(15, mean=1, sd=0.15))`

and the plot I want to make is

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=year, y=var1)) + 
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=var1-var1_sd, ymax=var1+var1_sd))
```

I want to make the exact same plot for a number of variable combinations, so I wrote a wrapper:

```
myplot <- function(data, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  sdvar <- paste0(quo_name(var), "_sd")
  ggplot(data,aes(x=year, y=!!var)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=!!var-!!sdvar, ymax=!!var+!!sdvar))
}
```

When I call `myplot(data, var1)`, I get the error *"Error in (~var1) - "var1_sd" : non-numeric argument to binary operator"*

I think the problem is in the linear operation between the unquoted variables? Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, `sdvar` is just a string. You can turn it into a symbol with `sym()`, and then the unquoting works:

```
myplot <- function(data, var) {
    var <- enquo(var)
    sdvar <- sym(paste0(quo_name(var), "_sd"))
    ggplot(data,aes(x=year, y=!!var)) +
        geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=!!var-!!sdvar, ymax=!!var+!!sdvar))
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was so close! Thank you, I really struggle with non-standard evaluation...

Comment: do you happen to know of a good resource to better understand the difference between strings, symbols, quosures, and variable names?

Comment: I still find a lot of this confusing myself. I'm on the lookout for a good resource that sums all these things up - I just searched and found [this book](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) which looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

After converting to symbol as suggested by @Marius, you could also use curly-curly operator (`{{}}`)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)


myplot <- function(data, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  sdvar <- sym(paste0(quo_name(var), "_sd"))
  ggplot(data,aes(x=year, y={{var}})) +
      geom_pointrange(aes(ymin={{var}}-{{sdvar}}, ymax={{var}}+ {{sdvar}}))
}

myplot(data, var1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ronak, what is the difference between bang-bang and curly-curly? Is any one more efficient than the other?

Comment: @Mar I am not sure about the efficiency but curly-curly was introduced some months back and is the successor for bang bang. You can read about it here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/

Comment: am I interpreting correctly that if I use curly-curly then I don't need the line `var <- enquo(var)`?

Comment: If you are only dealing with `var` then you don't need it but here since you also need to generate `sdvar`, we need to convert `var` to string first.